# An If statement with 2 variables?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to adjust this form that measures and calculates carpets, the form simply allows you to pick a width 4m or 5m, the length you want and the price range, but heres my issue, Im trying to make it so that an alert box will pop up if the width is 5m and the price range is over 9.99

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["quickestimate"]["width"].value;
  var p = document.forms["quickestimate"]["pricerange"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "5") {
     // your allowed 5m wide just under 9.99
     return true;
  } else if (p == null || p >= "9.99"){
     alert("Can't have 5m Wide and over £9.99");
     return false;
  }
}
```

any ideas where I am going wrong ?

Comment: values from inputs are strings, so the null check will never be true (unless the input doesn't exist) if x = 5 then you return from the function, so you wouldnt get to your alert, the check against x and p need to be in the same conditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["quickestimate"]["width"].value;
  var p = document.forms["quickestimate"]["pricerange"].value;
  if ((x == "5") && (p >= "9.99")) {
     // your allowed 5m wide just under 9.99
     return true;
  } else {
     alert("Can't have 5m Wide and over £9.99");
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: x and/or p wont be null if the input exists

Comment: This makes even less sense than the original.

Comment: Actually it works and thats all I wanted for someone to answer the question.

Comment: I will do when the 5 mins are up.

Comment: @MrJoshFisher Seriously? You want the form to be valid only if width is exactly 5 and price range is greater than or equal to £9.99?

Comment: @MrJoshFisher great :D

Comment: @MrJoshFisher This answer does the opposite of what you asked.